# I have an array of objects stored in local storage, but I want to be able to use the contents of each of the object in different parts of the website

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multiselect-react-dropdown

[image: array of objects]

i am expecting to be able to target the id and use it where I want and the name and also use it where i want.

Comment: Could you provide a code snippet showing what have you tried? You can access localStorage with `localStorage.getItem("key")`

Comment: const id = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("PaymentItemId"));
    console.log(id, "checking result for id");

Comment: and what is the problem then?

Comment: That's what I did and I still get the array of objects, I want to get an array targeting only the ids

Comment: local storage does not provide what you want. Better for you to connect this data to a store, f.e. Redux, or create a store by useReducer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Redux & Redux Toolkit in ReactJS and make your store with reducers and actions then using useSelector Hook to use it in any component.

Tutorials for this:
https://redux-toolkit.js.org/tutorials/quick-start

Answer (score 0):

After you get the array of objects from the localStorage, you can use `.find()` to find a single object by `id`, for example. You could also use `.filter()` if you need to filter array down based on some other property.

Answer (score 0):

If you store an array of objects, you can't just take an object from local storage, you should take whole array and then take an object from it.

The other way, you can store those objects under different keys, then you will be able to just get one exact object from local storage.